# what happens to documents when name change

Tags: halacha, names, ketubah, legal-documents

if someone changed a name, (got a Jewish name, added a name to his name...)

what happens to his/her document

for example kesubah, does he need a new kesuba, or the old one is good

how about if someones father changed his (the fathers) name,
what happens to his (the sons) documents (the sons name in them was written with his fathers old name)

sources please